# SSIS File System and For Each Loop Container

Tags: ssis

I have set of files which arrive in the below fashion

mmyy_dgmaker.csv
mmyy_xlsx

I have attached the photo of the files
[image]

In my SSIS task I have taken for each loop container

- In expression I have given file directory as varfiledirectory
- variable as varfilename
  Inside for each loop
  I have taken file system task editor
  Source variable is : var source
  Destination is var _ destination
  for var destination I have used below expression
  [image]

Now the problem is it is replacing for all the file in the folder with 15 characters from right which should not be the case need help so that it should take only those files specifically has more length and the rest should be imported as it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly the script should look like:

```
@[User::Var_Destination_Path] + 
    (LEN(@[User::Var_File_Name]) > 15 ? 
        LEFT(@[User::Var_File_Name], LEN(@[User::Var_File_Name]) - 15) + ".csv" : 
        @[User::Var_File_Name])
```

This expression evaluates whether the filename has more than 15 characters. If the condition is met, it removes the final 15 characters from the filename and adds the "*.csv" extension. If the filename has 15 or fewer characters, it remains unchanged.

Instead of replacing with empty characters I used LEFT function.

Comment: I used the above expression in my task I'm getting error as
The length -15 specified for function "LEFT" is negative and is not valid. The length parameter must be positive. code 0xC00470E7